# Please help ensure text is preserved in full via bash parsing

Tags: bash, parsing, filenames, filepath

Can someone please help correct my bash text parse line ?

Program: eyeD3

### File

`PathAndPlaylists.txt` [Tab delimited]

/home/Music/A/Average White Band/1975/Average White Band - Cut The Cake.mp3 1970-POP; -ALL-POP; 1970-ALL

```
cat PathAndPlaylists.txt | while read z; do filename=$(echo "$z" | cut -f1) playlists=$(echo "$z" | cut -f2) eyeD3 --no-tagging-time-frame --no-zero-padding --set-text-frame=TCOM:"$playlists" "$filename" done
```

### Objective

Use each absolute file/path in the text file above (PathAndPlaylists.txt) for the program 'eyeD3' to use the second tab separated field (1970-POP; -ALL-POP; 1970-ALL).

**PROBLEM:** I can't ensure the file/path will be treated as text without having some characters fail the code. e.g. commas.

Best regards.

Comment: Please format your code in a readable way.

Comment: Still rejecting commas... `while IFS=$'\t' read filename playlists; do eyeD3 "$filename" ; done < PathAndPlayList.txt` e.g. **File Not Found: /home/Music/Compilations/Billboard Year End Hot 100/0-9/10,000 Maniacs/1993/10,000 Maniacs - Because The Night.mp3**

Comment: If `eye3D` does not like commas in its input, that's a separate discussion.  What sort of error message do you get, or what are the symptoms?  Does it have documentation about this restriction?

Comment: eyeD3 accepts commas; e.g. eyeD3 "/home/Music/0-9/10,000 Maniacs - Because The Night.mpg". **Errors**; 1.)File Not Found: 2.) 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 5: ordinal not in range(128). PROBLEM: When reading/feeding each line of file/path to a bash script, I can't ensure text e.g. "/path/file/x.mp3"

Comment: Does the file `/home/Music/Compilations/Billboard Year End Hot 100/0-9/10,000 Maniacs/1993/10,000 Maniacs - Because The Night.mp3` actually exist on your system?

Comment: Yes, the file does exist.(typo, should end in .mp3). Do you have a solution ?

Comment: The "ordinal not in range" error hints that you have non-ASCII characters without a well-defined character set.  Without access to your data, we can only speculate that `eyeD3` cannot tolerate accented characters, or needs a setting to indicate the character set to use.

Comment: I'm also speculating that commas in the TCOM field are problematic, not because I know anything about the field, but because you are repeatedly saying that commas are problematic.  Obviously, commas in the file name should be completely undramatic.

Comment: tripleee. Please note above, if I enclose the path/file with "" eyeD3 has no problem with any character whatsoever. I have also verified gnome-terminal and system are set to utf-8 so this should not interfere.I am still seeking a rock solid method in the bash scripting to treat **"10,000 Émulsions"** as acceptable without choking on the comma or É. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is tab delimited, just tell the shell so.

```
while IFS='        ' read filename playlists; do
    eyeD3 ... "$playlists" ... "$filename"
done <PathAndPlaylists.txt
```

The IFS= value should be a literal tab character.  If you work at the prompt, you might need to type something like ctrl-V tab to get a literal tab.  Check your shell's documentation for specifics.

Comment: `IFS=$'\t'` should work. More typing, but easier to for cut-and-paste.